# Can I change the height of scroll bar thumb?

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I'm trying to change the height of the scrollbar thumb only, the scrollbar track must remain as it is.

I'm trying

```
.lc-graphic__figure::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background-color: var(--thumbBG);
 border-radius: 15px;
 min-height: 5px;
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work.

Here is my code:
[https://codepen.io/basia345/pen/wvRVMOV](https://stackoverflow.com)

Thank you!

a picture of what it should look like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11roL.png)